# R problems with encoding after reading from MS SQL via ODBC

Tags: r, windows, encoding, odbc

We have a database and R scripts running on different virtual machines.
First we connect to db

```
con <- dbConnect(
  odbc(),
  Driver = "SQL Server",
  Server = "server", Database = "db", UID = "uid", PWD = "pwd",
  encoding = "UTF-8"
)
```

and gathering the data

```
data <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM TableName")
```

The problem is following: when different machines running the same script, for some of these we face character variables encoding issues.

For example, this is what we have on machine A

```
> data$char_var[1]
[1] "фамилия"
> Encoding(data$char_var[1])
[1] "UTF-8"
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251"
> Encoding(data$char_var[1]) <- "1251"
> data$char_var[1]
[1] "РіСЂРµРІС†РµРІ"
```

and this is what we have on machine B

```
> data$char_var[1]
[1] "<e3><f0><e5><e2><f6><e5><e2>"
> Encoding(data$char_var[1])
[1] "UTF-8"
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_CTYPE=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_MONETARY=Russian_Russia.1251;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=Russian_Russia.1251"
> Encoding(data$char_var[1]) <- "1251"
> data$char_var[1]
[1] "фамилия"
```

First script returns gibberish, but it prints the initial value correctly. The same code running on machine B initially prints utf-8 and then returns encoded values. What could be the reason for such a difference?

As a result we want a script that would have the same "фамилия" output value to show it on a dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the result of your call to `Encoding(data$char_var[1])`, both machines are declaring the returned results to be encoded using UTF-8.

On the first machine, that appears to be true, because you're seeing valid output.  Then you mess it up by declaring the encoding incorrectly as `"1251"`, and you see gibberish.

On the second machine, the result comes to you declared as UTF-8, but it isn't (which is why it looks like gibberish to start).  When you change the declared encoding to be `"1251"` it looks okay, so that's what it must have been all along.

So you have two choices:

- Make sure both machines are consistent about what they return from the `dbGetQuery`.  You can handle either encoding, but you need to know what it is and make sure it's declared correctly.
- Alternatively, try to detect what is being returned, and declare it appropriately.  One way to do this might be to put a known string in the database and compare the result to that.  If you know you should get `"фамилия"` and you get something else, switch the declared encoding. You could also try the `readr::guess_encoding()` function.

One other issue is that some downstream function might only be able handle one or the other of UTF-8 and 1251 encodings.  (Windows R is really bad at non-native encodings, and UTF-8 is never native on Windows.)  In that case you may want to actually convert to a common encoding.  You use the `iconv()` function to do that, e.g.

```
iconv(char_var, from = "cp1251", to = "UTF-8")
```

will try to convert to UTF-8.